# How expensive is calling size() on List or Map in Java?

Tags: java

How expensive is calling size() on List or Map in Java? or it is better to save size()'s value in a variable if accessed frequently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on the actual implementation class.  For some `Map` and `Collection` classes, `size()` is a cheap constant-time operation.  For others, it may entail counting the members.

<strike>The [Java Collections Cheatsheet (V2)](http://www.coderfriendly.com/2009/05/23/java-collections-cheatsheet-v2/) is normally a good source for this kind of information, but the host server is currently a bit sick.</strike>

The "coderfriendly.com" domain is no more, but I tracked down a copy of [the cheat-sheet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/140013061/Java-Collections-Cheatsheet) on scribd.com.

The cost of `size()` will also be obvious from looking at the source code.  (And this is an "implementation detail" that is pretty much guaranteed to not change ... for the standard collection classes.)

**FOLLOWUP**

Unfortunately, the cheatsheet only documents the complexity of `size` for queue implementations.  I think that's because it is `O(1)` for all other collections; see @seanizer's answer.

Comment: +1 for everything but I'd like to give an extra +1 for the Collections Cheatsheet (it's really great)

Comment: Your link is taking me all over the place.

Comment: @DrewBuckley - fixed.  For the record, that's what happens to domain names that get "parked".

Answer (score 4):

`List` and `Map` are interfaces, so it's **impossible to say**. For the implementations in the Java Standard API, the size is generally kept in a field and thus not performance-relevant.

Answer (score 3):

for `ArrayList` the implementation is like

```
   public int size() {
       return lastIndex - firstIndex;
   }
```

So  **not over head**

You can check the source code for detailed info **for your required Impl**.

Note: The source given is from openjdk

Comment: In my ArrayList version 1.56 it already gets it from a private int size attribute.

Comment: @Manny This is the source from OpenJDK

Answer (score 3):

For most Collections, calling `size()` is a constant-time operation. There are however some exceptions. One is [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). From the Javadoc of [the size() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#size%28%29):

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, this method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these queues, determining the current number of elements requires an O(n) traversal.

So I'm afraid there's no generic answer, you have to check the documentation of the individual collection you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Implement it, then test it. If it is slow, take a closer look.

"Premature optimisation is the root of all evil." - D. Knuth

Also: You should not require certain implementation features, especially if they are black-boxed. What happens if you replace that list with a concurrent list at a later date? What happens if Oracle decides to rewrite List? Will it still be fast? You just don't know.

Comment: It's *Premature optimization*. Knuth is American :-)

Comment: *"What happens if Oracle decides to rewrite List?"* (nitpick - presumably you mean a list implementation class).  A rewrite that made `size` an `O(N)` operation would break huge numbers of applications.  Oracle would be crazy to do this.  It's about as likely to happen as Microsoft open-sourcing Windows.  (Less likely actually ...)

Comment: @Stephen C: You're completely right, Oracle would be insane to change the behaviour of Size() in ArrayList at this date (and I would still bet that such changes have happened in all major language labraries at some point). It is /probably/ not of relevance in this specific example. The prime issue is a later replacement of implementation, from ArrayList to ConcurrentList, some third party List or what have you.

Comment: @Kdansky - that would be a concern.  That's why you have to **think** when substituting one collection type for another.

Comment: *"I would still bet that such changes have happened in all major language libraries at some point"*.  Hopefully only while the relevant libraries were in Alpha or Beta.  Library developers who make breaking changes to production libraries without (at least) deprecating the old methods are going to make their users / clients very angry.

Comment: Wouldn't be stack overflow without the obligatory "premature optimization..." answer. He didn't ask if he should optimize, he asked how complex the size operations were.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry much about that. The list implementations keep track of size. The cost of the call is just O(1). If you are very curious, you can read the source code for the implementations of Collection's concrete classes and see the size() method there.

Comment: IMO, you should worry about that (in general), Schlemiel painter algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation gets it from a private pre-computed variable so it's not expensive.

Answer (score 0):

No need to store.Its not at all expensive.Check the source of [ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) and [HashMap](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think some implementations of LinkedList count the total for each call.  The call to a method itself can be a little taxing, but only if we're talking about large iterations or driver coding for hardware would that really be an issue.

In either case, if you save it to a local variable, there won't be any problems.